# ¿Se pueden enviar archivos y al mismo tiempo un JSON dentro la de misma función?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript, postgresql, express

Estoy realizando una API desde nodejs con typescript, donde tengo un end-point que se encarga de enviar archivos a AWS y retorna el nombre del archivo para después enviar el nombre del archivo mas un json que viene de parte del request.body y los archivos de request.files pero al momento de probar la función con postman no reconoce el json si estoy en el apartado del form-data y lo mismo pasa si estoy en el raw del body toma el json pero no los archivos por lo que veo no puedo enviar estas dos cosas dentro de la misma petición, ¿Cómo tendría que configurar mi end-point para que realice esta función dentro de la misma petición?

```
export const guardarvaloraciondbt = async (req:Request, res:Response) => {
try {        
    const pool2 = new Pool(conexionDB.get_config)

    const files: any = req.files
    const ojoIZ: string = await subirImgAws(files.ojoIZ)
    const ojoDE: string = await subirImgAws(files.ojoDE)
    const tac:   string = await subirImgAws(files.tac)

    const parametros: string[] = [req.body, ojoIZ, ojoDE, tac]
    const consulta: string = 'select * from guardar_treporteexamendbt_web($1, $2, $3, $4)';
    const response : QueryResult = await pool2.query(consulta, parametros);
    const notificacion = response.rows[0].guardar_treporteexamendbt_web
    res.status(200).json({"res": ojoIZ, "res2": ojoDE, "res3": tac, "notificacion": notificacion});
    } catch (error) 
    {    
        res.status(500).json('Fallo en la consulta de los registros:  ' + error);
    }
};
```

Comment: si se puede, consulta lo que es un formdata https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Answer (score 0):

Para poder enviar tanto el cuerpo de la solicitud como los archivos en una misma solicitud, puedes utilizar el encabezado Content-Type: multipart/form-data en tu solicitud HTTP. Con este encabezado, puedes enviar tanto los datos en formato JSON en el cuerpo de la solicitud como los archivos en el cuerpo de la solicitud, utilizando la propiedad request.body para acceder a los datos en formato JSON y la propiedad request.files para acceder a los archivos enviados en la solicitud.

Por ejemplo, tu código podría verse así:

```
export const guardarvaloraciondbt = async (req:Request, res:Response) => {
  try {        
    const pool2 = new Pool(conexionDB.get_config)

    const files: any = req.files
    const ojoIZ: string = await subirImgAws(files.ojoIZ)
    const ojoDE: string = await subirImgAws(files.ojoDE)
    const tac:   string = await subirImgAws(files.tac)

    const parametros: string[] = [req.body, ojoIZ, ojoDE, tac]
    const consulta: string = 'select * from guardar_treporteexamendbt_web($1, $2, $3, $4)';
    const response : QueryResult = await pool2.query(consulta, parametros);
    const notificacion = response.rows[0].guardar_treporteexamendbt_web
    res.status(200).json({"res": ojoIZ, "res2": ojoDE, "res3": tac, "notificacion": notificacion});
  } catch (error) 
  {    
    res.status(500).json('Fallo en la consulta de los registros:  ' + error);
  }
};
```

Si deseas enviar la solicitud utilizando Postman, puedes seleccionar la opción "form-data" en la pestaña "Body" y añadir tanto los campos de datos en formato JSON como los archivos que deseas enviar en la solicitud.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver tu problema.